# Encrypting video sent from Android device to server

Tags: android, video, encryption, h.264, mjpeg

We have developed an Android application that streams H264 & MJPEG video from the android device to a server through internet connection, using HTTP protocol both for authentication and video.
Right now, the authentication part is encrypted using RSA.

Now we are looking for a solution that will allow us to send the video encrypted with the minimum additional computational cost.

Symmetric key encryption such as AES over the whole video is unacceptable.
Looking for any advice on how to do it, either on H264, MJPEG or both.

Answer (score 2):

"Symmetric key encryption such as AES over the whole video is unacceptable." Why? Use a stream cipher and encrypt the chunks you send as you send them.

The simplest way to send the video encrypted is of course to use HTTPS (TLS) instead of plain HTTP to send the video to the server.

Comment: Though I haven't tested it, I'm quit sure It'll effect performance on both the device and server (which suppose to be scalable and be able to handle a number of up to 100 devices). With H264 for example, encrypting only the key frames should be enough in terms os security and with such solution I'm already encryption less than 50% of the video. Looking for a solution like that, though I'll run some benchmarks with AES to see how well if performs.